# Why is there H^+ ions in Hcl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I am new to chemistry, just learning the basics. So, my question is: Hydrogen and chlorine form a covalent bond, so shouldn't they both be negative as they both got an electron by sharing? Why is H positive even though it has formed a covalent bond? If Hydrogen had formed an ionic bond by giving an electron, then it would have been clear, but why covalent?

Comment: You mean HCl. // If you and your friend share 2 cookies, does it mean both of you can eat 2 cookies? No, it would need 4 cookies.

Comment: You might find answers also among the related posts listed next to the main post. For instance: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2698/why-does-the-hydroxide-ion-have-a-negative-charge?rq=1 Please look through existing answers on the site, you are likely to find an answer to this basic question there.

Answer (score 1):

Gaseous/liquid $\ce{HCl}$ has covalent bond, sharing 2 electrons. As they are shared, atoms do have them solely for themselves and therefore they cannot be both negative. 2 shared electrons means effectively 1 electron for each atom as before bonding.

The shared electrons are partially attracted toward the $\ce{Cl}$ atom, which obtains partial negative charge while $\ce{H}$ atom partial positive charge. This forms an electric dipole by displaced charges.

When HCl is dissolved in water, water molecules break H-Cl bond into ions, which get hydrated:

$$\ce{HCl(g) ->[H2O]H+(aq) + Cl-(aq)}$$

Comment: But in Na + H2O => NaOH is formed, which means Sodium gives up its electron to OH, right? And the left one H makes up H2 after we balance the equation, as you said, the electrons are more attracted to Cl, so in the way, same way electrons should also be more attracted to Oxygen in H2O. Then when does the one H ( Which forms H2) gets out of H2O with its electron, even though the electron is more attracted to Oxygen?

Comment: Sodium gives electron to water, forming highly unstable, but detectable hydrated electron. This attaches to partially positive H (H(+)-OH(-)), forming later H2, leaving OH- behind.

Comment: One more question, sir: why does only one H+ detaches from H-O-H?  Why not the 2nd one, too? Thank you!!

Comment: Because OH- is not H2O.

Comment: And because it is rather difficult to remove something positive from a negative target